# Pull mongo data to ejs template

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I have the following basic document in mongo:

```
connecting to: test
> db.car.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5657c6acf4175001ccfd0ea8"), "make" : "VW" }
```

I am using express, mongodb native client (not mongoose) and ejs.

```
 collection.find().toArray(function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else if (result.length) {
       console.log('Found:', result);
        mk = result;
        console.log('mk = ', mk);
      } else {
        console.log('No document(s) found with defined "find" criteria!');
      }
        //Close connection
      db.close();
    });
  }
});
```

Here is the render code:

```
// index page
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.render('pages/index', { make: result });
    });
```

And i want to pass the data make:  VW into my index.ejs file:

```
 <h2>Cars:</h2>
        <h3>My favorite make is <%= make %>
```

This should be real simple and straightforward but i just don't understand how to pass the "mk" variable (which i can console.log to the screen) to be rendered by the ejs view?

Comment: To get clarified, what is the output of `result` in your render code. Could you `console.log` the `result` object in render code and add that in your question?

Comment: The query method [find()] should be in the route method [app.get()]. Then you can assign the query result as an `EJS` variable like the Michelem's answer. Additionally, I think you use the `node-mongodb-native` module to access the MongoDB. If you want to store data in specific form like number or date, you should use an ORM like Mongoose. Otherwise your data is stored as a string. Generally this is a problem when handling a date like a 'date of birth' or a number like 'total amount' etc. So you will need to convert the values every time when you want use these in a calculation. Good luck..

Comment: $ node app-mongo.js
8080 is the port
Connection established to mongodb://localhost:27017/test
Found: [ { _id: 5657c6acf4175001ccfd0ea8, make: 'VW' } ]
mk =  [ { _id: 5657c6acf4175001ccfd0ea8, make: 'VW' } ]

Answer (score 1):

You should use the find method inside the route (or with a callback) to get the result and render it:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    collection.find().toArray(function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status('400').send({error: err});
        } else if(result.length) {
            console.log('Found:', result);
            mk = result;
            console.log('mk = ', mk);
            res.render('pages/index', {make: mk});
        } else {
            console.log('No document(s) found with defined "find" criteria!');
            res.status('400').send({error: 'No document(s) found'});
        }
        //Close connection
        db.close();
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks Michelem.  I have modified the code as per your suggestion above.  Now when i pass the 'mk' variable to ejs i get the following on the html page:  
Cars:
My favorite make is [object Object]

Comment: What is the variable name?  result, res, make or mk?
<%= <var?>%>

Comment: You have to get the property of the object you need, I don't kwon what you need to print, probably something like `<%= make.theproperty %>`. Also the object could be an array of results so you need to loop it. Please approve this answer and write another question if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, your are outputting an array of JSON objects

Here is one way to visualise it:

```
[{a:b},{a:b},{a:b},{a:b}];
```

If you want the first result it would be array[0].a

so you simply need to call it this way:

```
<%= make[0].(your database key here) =>
//example
<%= make[0].name =>
```

A more sensible way to get this done would be to iterate through the array and output only the result you want on the server side. If you send all your data to your client you might have security issues depending on what you send.

Answer (score 0):

It should be simple, but you are defining `mk` just like this: `mk = result` So because you want to pass a variable to an `ejs` file you need

```
"var mk = result"
```

Have a good day, Ben.